# How to start python program at boot on Arch Linux ARM?

Tags: python, arch-linux, raspberry-pi, systemd

I am running Arch Linux ARM on my Raspberry Pi, and I need to start a python (which should keep running until it either crashes or the machine loses power) program at boot with no input at all from the user after boot.

I'm a little new to Arch, so I don't really know how to write services and all that.

Answer (score 7):

A *systemd* service file would look like this: (required parts in bold)

```
[Unit]
Description=Foo service

[Service]
ExecStart=/path/to/script.py
# "Type=forking" or "Type=oneshot" may also be needed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You can also make it start as a specified user, restart on crash, and so on. See [systemd.exec(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) and [systemd.service(5)](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) for all the available options.

Put your service file in `/etc/systemd/system/name.service`.

To make it start on boot, use `systemctl enable name.service`.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't have to. You can add it to crontab as a user. run crontab -e to edit the crontab, and add the line `@reboot /path/to/command.py` In some cases you may need to explictly call python or run a bash script that runs the python file. Nonetheless, crontab's probably the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

I have recently installed arch linux (commandline only, no X) on a [pokini](http://pokini.de).
My solution to starting a shell script, was to put it in
/etc/profile.d/myshellscript.sh

Comment: This killed my Raspberry Pi login (ssh)
for everyone else having this Problem, issue:
ssh user@host "rm /etc/profile.d/myshellscript.sh"